# How can I work out which process/thread owns the resource that my program is hanging on

Tags: windows, windbg, freeze

I have a user mode process which is hanging when calling NtClose.  That NtClose is hanging while trying to acquire a lock in the kernel.  I believe it's the lock to the handle table.  Here's the kernel part of the stack:

```
    THREAD fffffa800bd4fb50  Cid 277c.21d8  Teb: 000007fffff80000 Win32Thread: 0000000000000000 WAIT: (WrResource) KernelMode Non-Alertable
        fffffa80047bad20  SynchronizationEvent
    IRP List:
        fffffa80049f49c0: (0006,0430) Flags: 00000404  Mdl: 00000000
    Not impersonating
    DeviceMap                 fffff8a000008bc0
    Owning Process            fffffa800c195060       Image:         My_Service.exe
    Attached Process          N/A            Image:         N/A
    Wait Start TickCount      455527         Ticks: 223 (0:00:00:03.478)
    Context Switch Count      1703             
    UserTime                  00:00:00.015
    KernelTime                00:00:00.109
    Win32 Start Address 0x000000013f509190
    Stack Init fffff8800c3e0fb0 Current fffff8800c3e0790
    Base fffff8800c3e1000 Limit fffff8800c3db000 Call 0
    Priority 10 BasePriority 8 UnusualBoost 2 ForegroundBoost 0 IoPriority 2 PagePriority 5
    Child-SP          RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
    fffff880`0c3e07d0 fffff800`02ccc972 : fffffa80`0bd4fb50 fffffa80`0bd4fb50 fffff880`00000000 00000000`00000003 : nt!KiSwapContext+0x7a
    fffff880`0c3e0910 fffff800`02cddd8f : 00000000`00000000 fffff880`0af2d400 fffff880`00000068 fffff880`0af2d408 : nt!KiCommitThreadWait+0x1d2
    fffff880`0c3e09a0 fffff800`02cb7086 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0000001b 00000000`00000000 fffff880`009eb100 : nt!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x19f
    fffff880`0c3e0a40 fffff800`02cdc1ac : ffffffff`fd9da600 fffffa80`047bad20 fffffa80`03e1d238 00000000`00000200 : nt!ExpWaitForResource+0xae
    fffff880`0c3e0ab0 fffff880`016e6f88 : 00000000`00000000 fffff8a0`0d555010 fffff880`0af2d840 fffff8a0`0a71e576 : nt!ExAcquireResourceExclusiveLite+0x14f
    fffff880`0c3e0b20 fffff880`01652929 : fffffa80`06fc72c0 fffffa80`049f49c0 fffff880`0af2d550 fffffa80`0bd4fb50 : Ntfs!NtfsCommonCleanup+0x2705
    fffff880`0c3e0f30 fffff800`02ccea37 : fffff880`0af2d550 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Ntfs!NtfsCommonCleanupCallout+0x19
    fffff880`0c3e0f60 fffff800`02cce9f8 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff880`0c3e1000 fffff800`02ce2e42 : nt!KySwitchKernelStackCallout+0x27 (TrapFrame @ fffff880`0c3e0e20)
    fffff880`0af2d420 fffff800`02ce2e42 : 00000000`0000277c 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000002 fffff880`042f8965 : nt!KiSwitchKernelStackContinue
    fffff880`0af2d440 fffff880`016529a2 : fffff880`01652910 00000000`00000000 fffff880`0af2d800 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutEx+0x2a2
    fffff880`0af2d520 fffff880`016f3894 : fffff880`0af2d5f0 fffff880`0af2d5f0 fffff880`0af2d5f0 fffff880`0af2d760 : Ntfs!NtfsCommonCleanupOnNewStack+0x42
    fffff880`0af2d590 fffff880`01145bcf : fffff880`0af2d5f0 fffffa80`049f49c0 fffffa80`049f4da8 fffffa80`03ef5010 : Ntfs!NtfsFsdCleanup+0x144
    fffff880`0af2d800 fffff880`011446df : fffffa80`04e239a0 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`048cb100 fffffa80`049f49c0 : fltmgr!FltpLegacyProcessingAfterPreCallbacksCompleted+0x24f
    fffff880`0af2d890 fffff800`02fe3fef : fffffa80`049f49c0 fffffa80`0c195060 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`04aa93d0 : fltmgr!FltpDispatch+0xcf
    fffff880`0af2d8f0 fffff800`02fd1fe4 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0c195060 fffff880`01165cb0 fffff800`02c64000 : nt!IopCloseFile+0x11f
    fffff880`0af2d980 fffff800`02fd1da1 : fffffa80`0c195060 fffffa80`00000001 fffff8a0`18385220 00000000`00000000 : nt!ObpDecrementHandleCount+0xb4
    fffff880`0af2da00 fffff800`02fd2364 : 00000000`0000cae8 fffffa80`0c195060 fffff8a0`18385220 00000000`0000cae8 : nt!ObpCloseHandleTableEntry+0xb1
    fffff880`0af2da90 fffff800`02cd61d3 : fffffa80`0bd4fb50 fffff880`0af2db60 00000001`3f64afd8 00000000`00000000 : nt!ObpCloseHandle+0x94
```

My question is, how can I work out which other process/thread on the system has acquired this kernel resource using windbg?  (By the way I'm looking at a full system dump from a customer, I don't have this reproduced in a debugger)

Answer (score 3):

So the answer was to use `kdext*.locks`, this shows that the thread above was deadlocked with a System thread that belonged to one of Symantec's antivirus drivers.

The locks which were causing a problem here were kernel `ERESOURCE` locks. There's two versions of `!locks` I've discovered, one for user mode critical sections and the other for kernel mode locks